# VBA XPath finding nodes

Tags: xml, vba, xpath

Can't get XPath to work for me in next to last line below:

```
Sub x()
Dim sXML As String
sXML = "<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""yes""?>"
sXML = "<NewDataSet><MyTable>"
sXML = sXML & "     <Active>true</Active>"
sXML = sXML & "     <SQLServer>APCD03</SQLServer>"
sXML = sXML & "     <SQLDatabase>OIS</SQLDatabase>"
sXML = sXML & " </MyTable>"
sXML = sXML & " <MyTable>"
sXML = sXML & "     <Active>false</Active>"
sXML = sXML & "     <SQLServer>APCD04</SQLServer>"
sXML = sXML & "     <SQLDatabase>OIS</SQLDatabase>"
sXML = sXML & " </MyTable></NewDataSet>"

Dim xDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim nodelist As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
xDoc.loadXML (sXML)

Set nodelist = xDoc.documentElement.SelectNodes("MyTable") ' finds all nodes
Debug.Print nodelist(0).XML ' see example

Set node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("MyTable[Active='true']") ' can't find 'Active' node
Debug.Print node.Text

End Sub
```

Here is the nodeList(0).XML:

```
<MyTable>
   <Active>true</Active>
   <SQLServer>APCD03</SQLServer>
   <SQLDatabase>OIS</SQLDatabase>
</MyTable>
```

How do I use SelectSingleNode() to find the "active" node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `DocumentElement`.  You could use:

```
Set node = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MyTable/Active[text()='true']")
```

or

```
Set node = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MyTable/Active[.='true']")
```

Comment: Close, but these return just the <Active> element and not the node the contains Active=true. I need to extract the SQL server info for the active node. "MyTable[Active='true']" worked  as the XPath.